# iOS Photos app displays incorrect time for imported pictures

Tags: iphone, photos, ios, exif

I have photos, that I make with my camera in travel, imported to iCloud. All the pictures have a timestamp in EXIF properties in local time of the place I took them (GMT+2). Also, they have GPS coordinates set. I live in GMT+5 time zone.

But Photos app on my iPhone shows a wrong time to all imported pictures (-3 hours) and correct time for pictures, taken on iPhone. Because of that, all the pictures are mixed.

How can I fix that? Probably, I need to set some other EXIF attribute for them?

Comment: A set all known EXIF tags for the photos, but it still shows incorrect timestamp (apps that can show EXIF info shows correct timestamp). iCloud web page also shows correct time for photos, but an order of photos in the flow isn't correct.

Comment: I also found a mention of this problem [here](https://www.macworld.com/article/3397319/wrong-time-zone-shown-in-photos-in-ios-it-s-a-timely-bug.html)

Comment: Same issue here, still present on iOS 13 (in addition to duplicates of edited photos). File a radar/feedback report and hope for the best